# Lambda connect not working

Tags: pyqgis, event-listener

I got an issue and I don't know how it happened.

I got a function **connect** on **legendLayersAdded**. This function sets a lot of connections on the event of the layer.

I use a function that adds a few layers of a Database and it can be used multiple times with multiple views.

When I use the function the first time the layer is added the connection is made but the connect with **lambda** that adds layer to the parameter doesn't work.

If I use the function a second time on another schema to add a new layer all the connections work even the lambda.

If I delete and reload the layer that doesn't work the 1st time they connect the lambda.

Only the first load that doesn't have the lambda works and I don't know why. Can you help me?

```
def __init__(self, iface):

    QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(self.Func)


def Func(self, lLayer):

    for layer in lLayer:

        # this will not work 

        layer.selectionChanged.connect(lambda selected, deselected, clearAndSelect :  self.AfterSelection(selected,deselected,clearAndSelect, layer))

        #but this work 

        #layer.selectionChanged.connect(self.TestAfterSelection)
```

Edit: Funny thing if I open the python console the lambda works.
If I don't, the lambda doesn't work

Comment: may I give you some advice so that you can get a meaningful answer: add some code samples to your question, and please use https://www.deepl.com/ to translate from your native language 

Answer (score 0):

It was a Qgis problem. I uninstalled and reinstalled it and now it works perfectly.